# Data will not parse and extract into excel file?

Tags: excel, file, parsing, pandas, save

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
import time 
from datetime import datetime


path = "C:\\Users\s\Downloads\H\intraQuarter"

def Key_Stats(gather = "Total Debt/Equits (mrq) "):
statspath = path + '/_KeyStats'
stock_list = [x[0] for x in os.walk(statspath)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Unix','Ticker','DE Ratio'])

for each_dir in stock_list[1:25]: 
    each_file = os.listdir(each_dir)
    ticker = each_dir.split("\\")[-1] 
    if len(each_file) > 0: 
        for file in each_file:
            date_stamp = datetime.strptime(file, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S.html')
            unix_time = time.mktime(date_stamp.timetuple())
            full_file_path = each_dir+'/'+file

            source = open(full_file_path,'r').read()
            try:
                value = float(source.split(gather+':</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0])
                df - df.append({'Date':date_stamp,'Unix':unix_time,'Ticker':ticker,'DE Ratio':value,}, ignore_index = True)
            except Exception as e:
                pass

save = gather.replace(' ','').replace(')','').replace('(','').replace('/','')+('.csv')
print(save)
df.to_csv(save)



Key_Stats()
```

This is my code and everytime I open the excel sheet it just has the headers of the table but non of the data it should be extracting from the files. any idea on why its not copying the data?

Comment: It looks like there is a syntax error in your try,except statement. I would try printing out your exception rather than using a catchall like Exception as e: pass. Also, you may want to do an edit and fix some of the indentation.

Comment: what do you mean print the exception statement? Im still very new to all of this. and as for the indentation that is just because it never copies over well.

Comment: In the try,except statement you should replace  
    `...`
    `except Exception as e:`
        `pass`  
with  
    `...`
    `except Exception as e:`
        `print(e)`  Then comment what that prints out.